# Google App Script - set formulas over range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking for a fast way to set up formulas.
Let's say I have some data in column A. In column B I want it to be =A1*2, =A2*2 etc etc.
For now I have been using a loop to do it. Loop trough every row and set up appropriate formulas using

```
.setFormula(='A'+i)
```

However this process is extremely slow. Is there another way to do it? Without using loops? Please note that all the formulas are within the same row.

Comment: Try [setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String))

Answer (score 0):

The loop is not the problem, the problem is calling so many `.setFormula();` operations.

Instead of using the loop to set a formula in each row use it to build an array of formulas and then set this array of formulas using the `.setFormulas()` method.